# how to only use sub on when there are multiple values

Tags: r, regex, dataframe, gsub

So this is a short example of a dataframe:

```
x<- c("WB (16)","CT (14)WB (15)","ET (13)CITG-TILm (16)EE-SS (17)TN-SE (17)")
```

My question is how to get `sub(".*?)", "", x)`(or a different function) to work such that this will be the result:

```
x<-c("WB (16)","WB (15)","TN-SE(17)")
```

instead of

`x<-c("","WB (15)")`

I got different types of letters (so not only WB, CT and TN-SE),such as:

```
 "NBIO(15)"    "CITG-TP(08)" "BK-AR(10)"
```

So it should be a general function...
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
sub(".*[0-9]+[^)]\\)?([^)$])", "\\1", x)
```

Output will be as follows.

```
[1] "WB (16)"    "WB (15)"    "TN-SE (17)"
```

Where Input will be as follows.

```
> x
[1] "WB (16)"                                   "CT (14)WB (15)"                           
[3] "ET (13)CITG-TILm (16)EE-SS (17)TN-SE (17)"
```

***Explanation:*** Following is only for explanation purposes.

```
sub("                 ##Using sub function of Base R here.
                      ##sub works on method of sub(regex_to_match_current_line's_stuff, new_string/variable/value out of matched,regex, variable)
.*[0-9]+[^)]\\)       ##Using look ahead method of regex by mentioning .*(everything till) a ) is NOT found then mentioning ) there to cover it too so it will match till a ) which is NOt on end of line.
?                     ##? this makes sure above regex is matched first and it will move for next regex condition as per look ahead functoianlity.
([^)$])",             ##() means in R to put a value into R's memory to remember it kind of place holder in memory, I am mentioning here to keep everything till a ) found at last.
"\\1",                ##Substitute whole line with \\1 means first place holder's value.
x)                    ##Mentioning variable/vector's name here.
```

Answer (score 1):

I *think* that I understand what you want.  This certainly works on your example.

```
sub(".*?([^()]+\\(\\d+\\))$", "\\1", x)
[1] "WB (16)"    "WB (15)"    "TN-SE (17)"
```

**Details:** This looks for something of the form `SomeStuff (Numbers)` at the end of the string and throws away anything before it. SomeStuff is not allowed to contain parentheses.

Comment: what if there are non-digits within the parenthesis? just curious... something like `sub(".*[)]([^)]+[)]$)","\\1",x)` would work or use perl instead of capturing to speed it up `sub(".*\\)(?=[^)]+\\)$)","",x,perl = T)`